# Select if last 6 visits happened within 30 days

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal 2013, my report groups by `customer_id`. The details are the times(`datetime`) that the customer has visited. I've figured out how to detect a minimum of 6 visits, but I am want to check if those 6 visits happened within 30 days.

I want to show all of the visits for the customer, but I want to only show the groups that meet the criteria. Do I need to do a `Whileprintingrecords` to do a `datediff` between the first and 6th record for each group? How can I do this?

Here is what I have:

```
30 >= DateDiff ("DD", (if {Command.ROW} = 1 then {Command.Visit_START},
  (if {Command.ROW} = 6 then{Command.Visit_STOP}))
```

Comment: is the formula that you have written is working for required criteria... if yes then write this in supress of the group else is there any error then post that

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to sort the group in Descending order? I have an idea but it will be less work for you if they're grouped newest to oldest.

**WhileReadingRecords:**

In each group you'll need to determine the 1st and 6th visit. (You're currently suppressing any groups with less than 6.) To do this, I would make a Shared Variable called `Counter` that increments by one every record *and* resets every time it reaches a new group. (Set it to zero in the Group Header.)

Next you'll need two more Shared Variables called `FirstDate` and `SixthDate`. These populate with the date value if `Counter` equals one or six respectively. Just like `Counter` you'll reset these every time the group changes.

**WhilePrintingRecords:**

If everything works, you should now have the two dates values you need for calculations. Add an additional clause in your current Suppression formula:

```
....
AND
DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SixthDate)
```

Comment: If you're *not* able to sort in Descending order, let me know and I can revise the answer to account for that.